# Migrate from Xamarin.Forms to Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

I'll initiate a project in Xamarin.Forms. But in future probably some feature is limited in Forms, then it's possible to work in this specific view, and just this, use Xamarin.Android and maintain the rest of app in Forms.

How much difficult it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Forms has two primary mechanisms that allow you to access native platform features from within a Forms app: [Dependency Injection](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) and [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).  Neither is necessarily difficult to use; however, the complexity will depend on the nature of your use case.

Comment: You can also mix and match Forms and Android views.